# outlook for mac addin js

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-for-mac

I have outlook for mac version 15.34.0 and I created a addin with mailbox version 1.4 in the manifest file.
In compose mode, the addin is not visible but when I change to mailbox version to 1.3 the addin is visible.
In [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets?product=outlook) say that Outlook for mac support mailbox 1.4 but this not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Any build on or above 15.33 (170225) supports 1.4 in Mac outlook.
Are you using versionOverrides in manifest?
Without versionoverrides support in manifest, compose mode addin's not supported in mac outlook. If you want compose mode addin's then add versionOverrides support in manifest. If versionOverrides support is already added in the manifest, please share the snippet.